# How to integrate this Api in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to make a flutter shows air quality according to users location, i came across this api but I don't know to integrate it into the app.

[Api Link](https://morioh.com/p/57de4d935d28)

Comment: The documentation seems pretty detailed. What have you tried on your end? Are you facing some errors? Would appreciate if you show some code that you've tried

Comment: You can pretty much copy and paste the documentation, so where is the problem?

Comment: I don't know where to start from, previously I have worked with JSON data but here I don't see any API link ETC @pblead26

Comment: I don't know where to start from, previously I have worked with JSON data but here I don't see any API link ETC  @TheUltimateOptimist

Comment: Here you do not need to work with JSON data or make any request to some link, because  this api has its own dart package called "wiseair_flutter_services" that you simply add to your pubspec.yaml file and then you can use all the classes and functions detailed in the documentation to reach whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: The sense of such packages like wiseair_flutter_services is to make interacting with the API easier, abstracting all the tedious request-making stuff by offering concrete functions and classes that can be used instead to easily interact with the api.